# Convex hull doesn't properly cover points

Tags: sphere, convex-hull

Recently I've been trying to create a sphere in my project. I start by creating a Fibonacci sphere through this code and draw with `glDrawArrays`

```
void create_fibonacci_sphere(int radius, int num_of_points, float points[])
{   
    float golden_ratio = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2;
    float angle_increment = 2 * M_PI * golden_ratio;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_points; ++i)
    {
        float t = (float)i / num_of_points;
        float angle1 = acos(1 - 2 * t);
        float angle2 = angle_increment * i;

        float x = radius * sin(angle1) * cos(angle2);
        float y = radius * sin(angle1) * sin(angle2);
        float z = radius * cos(angle1);

        points[i * 3] = x;
        points[i * 3 + 1] = y;
        points[i * 3 + 2] = z;
    }
}
```

Which successfully plots out these points
[image: Fibonacci sphere points]

And then using [this](https://iq.opengenus.org/quick-hull-convex-hull/) tutorial I implement the [quickhull algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickhull) to perform a convex hull on the points to get a sphere, drawing using `glDrawElements` because the convex hull doesn't work with `glDrawArrays`, but all I get is [image: quickhull on previous points] [image: same picture but from the side]

the convex hull looks wrong, considering that this is 1000 sample points that outputs this many convex hulls. [image: coordinates of convex hull outputs] For reference, [this](https://rreusser.github.io/fibonacci-sphere/) is pretty much what I wanted / expected.

This is the code that implements the quickhull algorithm, performs the convex hull on the points and draws the sphere

```
typedef struct 
{
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;

int find_side(Point p1, Point p2, Point p) 
{
    int val = (p.y - p1.y) * (p2.x - p1.x) - (p2.y - p1.y) * (p.x - p1.x);
    if (val > 0)
        return 1;
    if (val < 0)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}

int dist(Point p1, Point p2) 
{
    return (p1.y - p2.y) * (p1.y - p2.y) + (p1.x - p2.x) * (p1.x - p2.x);
}

int line_dist(Point p1, Point p2, Point p) 
{
    return abs((p.y - p1.y) * (p2.x - p1.x) - (p2.y - p1.y) * (p.x - p1.x));
}

void quick_hull(Point a[], int n, Point p1, Point p2, int side) 
{
    int ind = -1;
    int max_dist = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        int temp = line_dist(p1, p2, a[i]);
        if (find_side(p1, p2, a[i]) == side && temp > max_dist) 
        {
            ind = i;
            max_dist = temp;
        }
    }

    if (ind == -1) 
    {
        printf("(%d, %d) ", p1.x, p1.y);
        printf("(%d, %d) ", p2.x, p2.y);
        return;
    }

    quick_hull(a, n, a[ind], p1, -find_side(a[ind], p1, p2));
    quick_hull(a, n, a[ind], p2, -find_side(a[ind], p2, p1));
}

void print_hull(Point a[], int n) 
{
    if (n < 3) 
    {
        printf("Convex hull not possible\n");
        return;
    }
    int min_x = 0, max_x = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) 
    {
        if (a[i].x < a[min_x].x)
            min_x = i;
        if (a[i].x > a[max_x].x)
            max_x = i;
    }

    quick_hull(a, n, a[min_x], a[max_x], 1);

    quick_hull(a, n, a[min_x], a[max_x], -1);

    printf("\nThe points in Convex Hull are:\n");
}

int radius = 10;
int num_of_points = 1000;
float vertices[num_of_points * 3];
create_fibonacci_sphere(radius, num_of_points, vertices);   
Point* point_list = malloc(num_of_points * sizeof(*point_list));
for (int i = 0; i < num_of_points; i++)
{
    point_list[i] = (Point) {vertices[i * 3], vertices[i * 3 + 1]};
    point_list[i] = (Point) {vertices[i * 3], vertices[i * 3 + 2]};
}

print_hull(&point_list[0], num_of_points);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, num_of_points, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, point_list);
```

Comment: Points on a sphere are their own convex hull - there's no concavity to bridge. So I don't think using a convex hull algorithm is appropriate here.